# Linux TCP/IP Connections Limit

Tags: command-line, 20.04, nvidia, 22.04, find

I want only 1 incoming connection from port 1000 to 65535 to be able to connect to the ubuntu server, how and in what way can it be done?

Comment: Do you mean one connection at a time, from any server? From one other server? What do you mean by "connect"? Please expand your question to make clear what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

This `iptables` rule will allow 1 TCP connection at a time for that port range.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --match multiport --dports 1000:65535 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 1 --connlimit-mask 0 -j DROP
```

**inspiring links**

- [How to globally limit total number of TCP connections with iptables?](https://serverfault.com/questions/539954/how-to-globally-limit-total-number-of-tcp-connections-with-iptables)
- [Iptables setting multiple multiports in one rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384817/iptables-setting-multiple-multiports-in-one-rule)

Comment: thanks for replay
I tested the method you mentioned and it disconnects correctly, but it doesn't connect again